# Search-like highlighting in NSTextView

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, highlight, nstextview

So, this is what I want :

- When a match is **highlighted** under Mac OS X (when using the "Find" Action), a specific *golden rounded box* is drawn around the match for an instant (animated) and then goes away.
- Is there any way I can programmatically trigger the very same function, and highlight a specific range in an `NSTextView`?

I'm sure there must be something like that out-of-the-box, but I definitely cannot find it...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I thought it was this one:

```
- (void)showFindIndicatorForRange:(NSRange)charRange
```

For NSTextView (docs [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTextView_Class/Reference/Reference.html)).

Comment: Great answer! Simple as that... (that's a typical thing for me and Cocoa : I search and search all around and I'm usually missing something THAT obvious!)