# is there a method available for Xcode's yellow find result rectangle?

Tags: xcode, cocoa, nstextview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Search-like highlighting in NSTextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10670240/search-like-highlighting-in-nstextview)

I thought i read here months ago that there is a cocoa method for this feature, but now i can't find it, or search for it's too many common words.
nothing yeilded in `NSTextView`, or `NSText` or `NSAttributedString`.

Did i *dream* this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- (void)showFindIndicatorForRange:(NSRange)charRange
```

- [Search-like highlighting in NSTextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10670240/search-like-highlighting-in-nstextview/10670258#10670258)

Unless this is a different question, I'm marking yours as a duplicate!